# Is it possible to pass a class as an argument when the same class has initialized?

Tags: c#, class, arguments

Class:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class MainService : IChat
{
    IChatCallback ChatCallback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IChatCallback>();
    Chat chat = new Chat(this);
    public void ShowChat()
    {
        chat.Show();
    }
    public void SendInstantMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        chat.RaiseMsgEvents(user, message);
        ChatCallback.InstantMessage(user, message);
    }
 }
```

Form:

```
public partial class Chat : Form
{
    MainService service;

    public Chat(MainService service)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        OnMsgReceivedEvent += new OnMsgReceived(callback_OnMsgReceivedEvent);
        this.service = service;
    }

    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        service.SendInstantMessage("Admin", txtMsg.Text);
    }
 }
```

The mainForm use the class like this:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    ServiceHost host;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCF_Server.MainService));
        host.Open();
    }
 }
```

In the main form, i just pass the class, no initializing, but in the class when `ShowChat()` called i need to show the chat form and get to this class method so i can send messages.

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: @skyfoot yea, i got "Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context"

Comment: You're trying to access `this` from your constructor. `this` hasn't been initialized yet.

Comment: @MurHafSoz: The code you've posted will compile, after changing the class `Chat` to `ChatForm`. So your code must be different to what you've posted.

Comment: @JonSkeet I apologize, i edited the code.

Comment: @MurHafSoz: Right - you can't use it in an instance variable initializer expression, but you *can* use `this` within a constructor.

Comment: @JonSkeet i'm really sorry, check the question again.

Comment: @MurHafSoz: Your question code still tries to use it in an instance variable initializer. Just move the initialization into the constructor body (separating it from the variable declaration), and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET is an object oriented language. In fact, every class is an object.

The error you are getting is because you're instantiating an object with "this" on the global level.

### UPDATE

Based on your update you could do the following and it will work. You might want to refactor this some more to ensure that it's not going to break any business rules etc.

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class MainService : IChat
{
    IChatCallback ChatCallback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IChatCallback>();
    //Changed this to be just a declaration. This will be null,
    // as there is no object yet, this is really just a pointer to nothing.
    //This tells the system that you might/are planning to use an object called 
    //chat, but it doesn't exist yet.
    Chat chat;

    // Get your default constructor going. This will create the actual chat object, allowing the rest of your class to access it.
    public MainService()
    {
         //instantiate it! (or as some of our co-ops say "We're newing it")
         chat = new Chat(this);
    }

    //now that chat is actually instantiated/created you can use it.
    public void ShowChat()
    {
        chat.Show();
    }
    public void SendInstantMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        chat.RaiseMsgEvents(user, message);
        ChatCallback.InstantMessage(user, message);
    }
 }
```

This is just a personal pet peeve, but having a function parameter the same name as a global variable is... well for me a no no.  I noticed this on your Chat.Chat(MainService) function.

Comment: Thanks alot, should i remove the first wrong part from my question?

Comment: Up to you. It would probably clear the question up more to help people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is, just create a method that takes this class of yours as a parameter and call it...

Answer (score 0):

As other posts have suggested, you'll want to re-consider how you instantiate your `chat` field within your `example` class. I would consider lazy loading the property, like so...

```
private ChatForm _Chat = null;
private ChatForm Chat
{
    get
    {
        if (this._Chat == null)
        {
            this._Chat = new ChatForm(this);
        }
        return this._Chat;
    }
    set { this._Chat = value; }
}
```

Using lazy-loading will ensure you're able to use the keyword `this` upon request.